# How to overload mapping with same prefix uri to different methods in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to map two different URI with the same prefix to two different handlers

POST "resource" -> resourcesBl.create

POST "resource/{path_variable}" -> resourcesBl.createOther

note - the request body for each one is different

and Spring doesn't do it automatically

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("resource") 
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private ResourcesBl resourcesBl;

    @PostMapping
    public Resource create(@RequestBody Resource resource) {
        return resourcesBl.create(resource);
    }

    @PostMapping("/{resourceName}"}
    public OtherResource create(@PathVariable String resourceName, @RequestBody OtherResource otherResource, ) {
        return resourcesBl.createOther(otherResource);
    }

}
```

Comment: These are two different mappings. What's the issue?

Comment: Also, you should probably remove the "resource" part of `@RestController("resource")`. That is a name for the Controller, not a mapping. You may want `@RequestMapping("/resource")`

Comment: Actually the second request body type is a string and when i did POST it told me body is missing (of course the request was with body). About your second comment - yes its a mistake here in the question ill edit it

Comment: The second request body is not a string. It's an `OtherResource`. It has a `PathVariable` of type String.

Comment: I mean in the code, not here..

Comment: So your actual code is different from what you've posted here? That would be relevant. You should post exactly what you're looking to do, as well as describe what problems you have. This code should work as-is.

Comment: Christopher Schneider - Thanks ! you right I accidentally wrote  @RestController("resource") instead of @RequestMapping("/resource")

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider - I can't copy exact the same code, because I have to focus in the problem and not my domain :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this solution with Postman, it works perfectly fine and takes the path variable, both mappings can be called with different bodies.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private ResourcesBl resourcesBl;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Resource create(@RequestBody Resource resource) {
        return resourcesBl.create(resource);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{resourceName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public OtherResource create(@PathVariable String resourceName,
                                @RequestBody OtherResource otherResource) {
        return resourcesBl.createOther(resourceName, otherResource);
    }
}
```

All requests with empty path params will be mapped to the first method, so both: "/resource" and "/resource/". Anything after the slash to the second.

Note: don't forget to use the path variable.